# Change Flat rate shipping method cost if a specific coupon is applied in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I have a specific coupon which is `special50`. When someone applied this coupon on the store then a new shipping method need to add. When current shipping method price is $50 (flat rate) and after applying coupon new shipping method, pricing will be $25. In a word, if you apply this coupon you will receive 50% OFF on products(which WooCommerce has already provided to us) and 50% OFF on shipping(which really I need).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_shipping_add_rate', 'add_another_custom_flat_rate', 10, 2 );
    function add_another_custom_flat_rate( $method, $rate ) {
        $new_rate          = $rate;
        $new_rate['id']    .= ':' . 'custom_rate_name';
        $new_rate['label'] = 'Shipping and handling'; 
    global $woocommerce, $wpdb;
        $coupon = "SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title='special50' AND post_type ='shop_coupon' AND post_status ='publish'";
        if(in_array($coupon_id, $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons)){
            $cost = 25; 
        }
        $new_rate['cost']  = $cost;
        $method->add_rate( $new_rate );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the following custom function hooked in `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook, without any need of creating an additional discounted flat rate. The following code will change the "flat rate" shipping method cost when 'special50' coupon is applied.

> You should first **"Enable debug mode"** in Woocommerce settings > shipping > Shipping options.

The code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'coupon_discount_on_flat_rate', 10, 2);
function coupon_discount_on_flat_rate( $rates, $package ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return $rates;

    // Checking for 'special50' in applied coupons
    if( in_array( 'special50', WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() ) ){
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            $has_taxes = false;
            // Targeting "flat rate" shipping method
            if( $rate->method_id === 'flat_rate' ){
                // Set 50% of the cost
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost / 2;

                // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
                        $has_taxes = true;
                        // set 50% of the cost
                        $taxes[$key] = $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] / 2;
                    }
                }
                if( $has_taxes )
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Dont forget to disable **"Enable debug mode"** once this has been tested and works.

Comment: It was a great solution. Thank you.